# F# interactive commands corresponds to ghci :t :i

Tags: haskell, f#, f#-interactive

I'm learning F# via F# interactive.

Is there commands that acts like GHCi `:t`, `:i`?

- `:t value` shows the type of value.
- `:i type` shows the top-level declarations of type.

Reference: [fsharp-interactive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *F# Interactive* you can just write the name of function to see its type. If, for example, you want to see the types of `id`, `string`, or `List.map`, just write them:

```
> id;;
val it : ('a -> 'a)

> string;;
val it : (obj -> string) = <fun:it@6-3>

> List.map;;
val it : (('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list)
```

That gives you functionality similar to `:t` in GHCi.

I'm not aware of any command that corresponds to `:i`, although I admit that it would be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why I asked about `:t` was, when I type `float;;`, it says the type of it is `int -> float`, although I expected `'T -> float` with constraint. Do you have any guess?

Comment: @MyBug18 I don't know why that happens, but I suspect that it may be related to how [casting and conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions) works in .NET. IIRC, `float` isn't really a function, but a built-in operator that goes looking for an underlying conversion method on the types in question...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you **never** type directly into FSI. Use an editor with F# support like Visual Studio, VS Code or Rider. Write code in the editor, select definitions or expressions in the code and send to FSI (usually with Alt-Enter). This will provide a much better experience and save you lots of time. The benefits:

- Type information on hover for any symbols (including the type parameters of a function and what they might be constrained to in a particular context)
- Live type-error checking over multiple functions/values
- Auto-complete suggestions
- Syntax highlighting
- No need to put `;;` at the end of any lines

I've been writing F# for several years with heavy use of FSI and after the first day I have never ever typed into FSI because there is no advantage in doing so.